# What's the status of BitInstant's debit card?

Tags: debitcard

http://www.engadget.com/2012/08/20/bitinstant-founder-says-bitcoin-debit-card-to-launch-within-next/

It's been almost four months. Where can I find the latest public information about this?

Answer (score 2):

This is still very much a project which is being worked on.  BitInstant hopes to bring you more info as everything progresses.  Thanks for your patience.